# Using RSA keys in Elixir / Erlang

Tags: cryptography, erlang, elixir, jwt, rsa

I am trying to verify a JWT token using RS256 and an RSA public key. However, I keep getting "ArgumentError"

Is this a correct way to pass in RSA key in Elixir / Erlang?

This is what I am doing:

```
[{_, key, _}] = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
|> :public_key.pem_decode

token = "__header__.__payload__.__sig__"
JsonWebToken.verify(token, %{alg: "RS256", key: key})
```

And here is the error I get:

> ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>      (crypto) :crypto.pkey_verify_nif(:rsa, :sha256, "header.payload.sig", <<7, 49, 241, 224, ..., 85, 4, 3, 19, ...>>, [])
>   (crypto) crypto.erl:420: :crypto.verify/6
>   (json_web_token) lib/json_web_token/jws.ex:103:
>   JsonWebToken.Jws.verified/3 (json_web_token)
>   lib/json_web_token/jwt.ex:89: JsonWebToken.Jwt.verify/2

Comment: It looks like you're passing in a X509 certificate? Then you need to use `public_key:pem_entry_decode/1` to parse the output from `pem_decode` and then extract the field with the public key. See the X509 subsection in http://erlang.org/doc/apps/public_key/using_public_key.html

Comment: You can have a look here: https://github.com/princemaple/elixir-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt/algorithm/rsa_util.ex

Comment: https://github.com/princemaple/elixir-jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt/algorithm/rsa.ex